# Reading File in C using System Call

Tags: c, file

I have tried several solution answers from the site but unable to understand what is going wrong with this code.

I am simply trying to read the file data.txt and print it. The file contains just 12 characters "abcd1234efgh".

fd comes out positive but "br" is 0 on executing the read. Please help out if anyone has some clue on this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main(int args,char* vargs[])
{
    int fd = 0;
    fd = open("data.txt",O_RDONLY);
    if(fd<=0)
        printf("Invalid file name");
    else{
        off_t fs =lseek(fd, (off_t) 0, SEEK_END);
        char buf[10];
        off_t br = read(fd,buf,10);
        printf("%s",buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'char buf[10];' do not bean-count. Use [256] minimim, (unless on RAM-restricted embedded system).

Comment: Why are you seeking to the end of the file before reading it?

Comment: The call to `lseek`tells you how long the file is, but it also fast-forwards to the end, from which there isn't anything to read. (And why determine `fs`, when you don't use the information?)

Comment: 'printf("%s",buf);' on a buffer that is not guaranteed NUL-terminated.

Comment: To retrieve the size of the file use `stat()` and remove the `lseek()` call there because as others pointed out after that call "*there is nothing to be read*".

Comment: I don't see  a system call in your code. THese are all C/POSIX standard library functions.

Comment: @Olaf: that is not a constructive comment.  The functions like `open()`, `close()`, `read()`, `write()`, `lseek()` are effectively system calls.  They're a very thin veneer over an assembly language system call.  They're how ordinary programmers make system calls.  You're making an unhelpful distinction.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I don't see any requirement they are system calls. The actual implementation is not relevant for the application. One should stay at the abstraction level used and mix them. This only leads to confusion. The problem is that a lot of teachers don't get it right themselves and pass their half-knowledge to their students. So yes, my comment was well justified, expecially as the title is missleading.

Comment: @Olaf: at the level at which you work, you may be right. At the level of someone asking this question, your comment isn't helpful, not least because you don't show how you might make a system call differently.

Comment: Note that you do not check the value returned by `read()` — you save it, but don't check it.  If `read()` returns -1, you hgot an error; if it returns 0, you got no data.  In context, if you get a positive value, it means another process extended the file between the time when you did the `lseek()` and when you did the `read()`, which is pretty remarkable timing.  Always check the return values from system calls.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: For the question it is completely irrelevant how `read` etc. are implemented. They are just used as defined. I don't see how the fact they **might** be implemented as syscalls is in any way relevant here. As I said, it just complicates things to even care about these implementation details. But yes, maybe I should have pointed **that** out better.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "Always check the return values from system calls" - So we need to know if that's a syscall or not? I'm somewhat missing the reason we don't need  to check the result of `fseek`? (**I** Know that's nonsense and we have to check these results, too. But beginners will take such statements from a very-high-rep user who very well knows all this literally. That's exactly the problem.

Comment: Since you are using POSIX functions (yes, they're functions that *probably* map closely to actual system calls but they're not system calls themselves - unless the actual system calls are really in the `openat()`, etc family in which case `open()` etc aren't even all that close to the system calls...), you can use the [POSIX standard `fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) to get the size of a file in bytes.

Comment: And to add to what @JonathanLeffler said about not checking the return value from `read()` - no matter how many bytes `read()` returns, it will not return a NUL-terminated string unless that's actually the entirety of the raw data it reads.  For example, if the file contains exactly four bytes of the ASCII characters "data", when you read four bytes, the first four bytes of the buffer you read into will contain "data". The fifth and later bytes in the buffer will still contain what they held before the `read()` call.  So your `read( fd, buf, 10 )` then `printf( "%s", buf );` will likely `SEGV`

Comment: I wonder if the lseek() call is there to try to get the length of the file? Presumably that length could be used to decide how much data to read, or sdomething. Of course, you'd have to seek back afterwards. I'm just wondering whether the code in question has been taken from some longer example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);

After this file pointer is set at the end of the file, so any further reading is unsuccessful. Just comment this instruction out, or change it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This:

> ```
> lseek(fd, (off_t) 0, SEEK_END);
> ```

seeks to (an offset of 0 from) the *end* of the file.  When you subsequently try to read, there are no bytes available past that point.  You should not need to seek at all if you want to read from the beginning of the file.